# How do we determine the API that Lync uses to capture and to render audio?

Tags: directshow, lync, ms-media-foundation

We are trying to determine the Windows API that Lync uses to render and to capture audio. How do we determine this? For instance, the Windows API that Lync uses could be one of these:

- DirectShow API,
- Media Foundation API,
- MMDevice API

Our use case is then to use this Windows API to create two virtual audio devices (VAD) that we can switch between with the Lync SDK. We need to do this because the [DeviceManager.AudioDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.device.devicemanager.audiodevices_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt%28v=office.14%29.aspx) only lists all-in-one devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following utility to find out the dependencies of a EXE.  It will help identify exactly what DLL are used and what APIs within those DLLs are used.

https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies